# Firefox stable version

Tags: google-play-store, firefox-for-android

If I go to the Play Store, and pull up Firefox, I notice that its version `88.0.0-beta.3`. I searched some more and found another version that is `87.0.0-rc.1`

I dont want a beta version or rc version, I want the most recent stable version.
How would I go about installing that?

Edit in case comment is removed: this site was helpful to me (`aarch64`):

https://archive.mozilla.org/pub/mobile/releases/

Comment: Looks like [this was the first time Mozilla released "rc.1" on the Release channel after a long release history](https://www.appbrain.com/app/firefox-browser%3A-fast-private-safe-web-browser/org.mozilla.firefox).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely just a temporary experience where the current stable release is technically labelled as "87.0.0-rc1".  I agree that it's a bit confusing, but I think it is most likely temporary.

The latest official release version of Firefox for Android can be obtain here:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mozilla.firefox

Alternatively, you can enter your email at the following page, and Mozilla will email you a link to the current official release version:
https://www.mozilla.org/firefox/mobile/

All the source code for Firefox mobile is available here (unlike many other browsers, there is no non-public source code used to create Firefox):
https://searchfox.org/mozilla-mobile/source/

BTW, all releases of the desktop version of Firefox are available via FTP, but I'm not aware of anything identical for the Android version.  For completeness, that FTP site for the desktop releases can be accessed via this link:
https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/

Answer (score 0):

You *can't* get the latest stable version till it is released. AFAIK, Firefox doesn't offer an independent stable release channel. Therefore, your Options :

- Wait for rc/ beta versions to be upgraded to stable.
- Downgrade to previous stable version, as explained in the [support page](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/install-older-version-Firefox).

> Firefox now includes downgrade protection to prevent corruption of user profile data. If you install an older version, you'll be prompted to create a new Firefox profile.

- [Switch to Firefox Extended Support Release (ESR) for personal use](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/switch-to-Firefox-Extended-Support-Release-ESR). Note that you will get latest security and stability fixes but not the latest features.
- Use a different browser till such time Play Store offers stable version.